# Does the word "that" refer to "your car" or "the key"?

Tags: ambiguity, relative-clauses

I have found the key to your car that you lost yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grammatically, it could be either. But in the real world, it has to be the key, doesn't it?

Comment: Would it be the same if i use "that" instead of "which"?

Comment: Yes.. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​